# ffmpeg copy stream preserving FPS

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I have a stream that I know is outputting at a certain frame rate (30 FPS). I want to use ffmpeg to make a copy of this stream and save it to disk.

I have the following command:

```
ffmpeg -i http://input/ -c copy -map 0 \
    -f segment -strftime 1 -segment_time 900 \
    -segment_atclocktime 1 -segment_format mp4 %Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S.mp4
```

But when I run the command, I see the following:

```
frame=   32 fps=3.9 q=-1.0 Lsize=N/A time=00:00:01.27 bitrate=N/A
```

Where it appears the FPS is hovers around ~4.0 FPS and `time` moves slower than real time.

I tried added `-re` (copy the rate of the input stream) and `-r 30` (manually set the rate to 30 FPS) flag specified before the input file, but it didn't seem to work.

I also read [a similar question here](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/13066/how-to-encode-a-video-at-30-fps-from-images-taken-at-7-fps) using `-framerate 30`, but that option doesn't exist in the man pages and is an `Invalid option`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

---

So I let the modified command (removing the flags `-c copy -map 0`) run for exactly 5 minutes. Running `ffprobe` yields:

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '2017-03-10_01-09-12.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.2.100
  Duration: 00:00:15.43, start: 0.066016, bitrate: 13416 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuvj420p(pc), 1024x768, 13414 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
```

Again, this only produces 15 seconds of video and I can't seem to get a 1:1 relationship between the input stream of 30 FPS and an output stream also in 30 FPS in real time. Playing the video yields something that's sped up.

Answer (score 1):

That's the processing speed i.e. 4 frames processed per second. It's not the output stream FPS. In any case, in stream copy mode, FFmpeg cannot alter output FPS, unless your input is a *raw* bitstream.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I removed `-c copy -map 0`. I see from the output that the `frame` counter is incrementing slower than 30 per second, FPS is around 2.0, and `time` is still going by slowly. When I play this back, the output looks sped up, even though the original stream is in 30 FPS.

Comment: Show the ffprobe output for one of the segments.

Comment: The output looks normal i.e. `30 fps`. How are you playing the result?

Comment: Just through VLC on my host machine. I definitely think something is wrong because 5 minutes of running ffmpeg yielded only 15 seconds of video. I would have obviously expected 5 minutes of output.

Comment: So, only one segment file was created in 5 minutes? You shouldn't use `-re` with a live input, only for file or fully formed network inputs.

Comment: I am not using `-re` and I just tested out the command not defining `-r 30` with the same effect.

Comment: Can you run your command for 15+ minutes with `-report` added and share that report?